# Why add operation is not working on a Mock?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

So I am trying again using a different controller to test a Cocoa desktop application using NUnit and Moq. The problem is, even after the .add() operation, I still don't have what I just added using the mock. More exactly, this is how I do the mock:

```
User user = new User
            {
                email = "test@gmail.com",
                password = "1",
                firstName = "Test",
                lastName = "Test"
            };
List<User> dataSource = new List<User>();
var userServiceMock = new Mock<IUserService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
userServiceMock.Setup(x => x.add(It.IsAny<User>()));
userServiceMock.Setup(x => x.getAllUsers()).Returns(dataSource);

var controller = new CreateAccountCoreController(userServiceMock.Object);

 //act
controller.submit();

//assert
Assert.That(dataSource.Contains(user));
```

and in controller is this:

```
readonly IUserService userService;
public CreateAccountCoreController(IUserService userService) 
{
    this.userService = userService;
}

public  void submit()
{

User user = new User
            {
                email = "test@gmail.com",
                password = "1234",
                firstName = "Test",
                lastName = "Test",
            };
            userService.add(user);
            List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
/*users it is empty here..*/

}
```

So my test always fails because the list of Users it is empty even after .add operation. Can you help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no place where you fill `dataSource` collection and you configure your mock to return it from `getAllUsers()` mock. So you will always get an empty collection from a method.

Use [`Callback()`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks) method to configure expected behavior:

```
userServiceMock.Setup(x => x.add(It.IsAny<User>())).Callback((User u) => dataSource.Add(u));
```

The second problem may be in comparing users in [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains) method. You need to tell `Contains` what makes two users equal. By default it will use `ReferenceEquals` which will only call two objects equal if they are the same instance.

Either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your User class or define an [`IEqualityComparer<User>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) class and pass that to `Contains`.

If two Users that have the same `email` are "equal" then the implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
   if(o.GetType() != typeof(User))
     return false;

   return this.email == ((User)o).email;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return email.GetHashCode();
}
```

You can read more about [value equality for a type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type).

Comment: this still fails the test... however, if I put dataSource.add(user) after I create the list the test pass indeed, but why the callback method is not working?

Comment: @Anastrasia i checked your code and Callback method works correctly. But threre can be a problem with User class. Please, check my update.